# Android map application not showing any map on device

Tags: android, android-mapview

This is my Google map key which I get after fingerprint `0o8CRg5BhPmqQB1pvyYZQNfJ2ZbpDMa6XFunRwA`

I placed it in `main.xml` file. Application works fine on emulator and shows map. But when I deploy it on real device it is not showing any map. It just show gray background not any map. What should I do?

**main.xml file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="0o8CRg5BhPmqQB1pvyYZQNfJ2ZbpDMa6XFunRwA"
android:enabled="true"
/>
```

**Manifest file**

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androidhive.googlemaps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <!--  Add Google Map Library -->
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"   />

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".AndroidGoogleMapsActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>

 <!-- Allow to connect with internet -->

   </manifest>
```

Comment: why my applicatin not show map on real device

Comment: Does it work properly in emulator? Which device you are using?

Comment: yes is work on emulator she me map but when i deploy in real device is not show

Comment: whqt key i used to sign in application?? MAp apiKey="0o8CRg5BhPmqQB1pvyYZQNfJ2ZbpDMa6XFunRwA"   this one??

Comment: Not key. I am asking about device that you are using for testing your application.

Comment: It should work. What is being displayed? Just blank screen? Or white screen with lines but no map?. Try reinstalling the app.

Comment: this image show on device  http://imgur.com/p3zKC

Comment: Ok. I had faced exact problem in emulator. But I had resolved that by creating a new emulator. Try uninstalling your application and reinstalling it. It might work.

Comment: no map show on emulator fine but not show on real device

Answer (score 2):

Have you generated keys for both the debug certificate and signing certificate you use when creating your APK file for the device. You'll get a gray screen with no map displayed if you've used the key for your debug certificate and not the key for your production signing cert.

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="PUT-KEY-FOR-PRODUCTION-CERT-HERE"
        />
```

More info for generating both debug and signing cert api keys here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey

Comment: i get this map api key  0o8CRg5BhPmqQB1pvyYZQNfJ2ZbpDMa6XFunRwA  and place in xml file is show map on emulator fine but not visibale in real phone device

Comment: You must have a key store for signing the apk files before they are uploaded to your device. If you're using eclipse then you would need to provide the location of the keystore file to sign your app before it will run on any device.

Comment: u mean default keystore which located on Eindows->Preference->Android->Build->  C:\Documents and Settings\Nazeer\.android\debug.keystore

Comment: Thats the debug key for running in emulator or debugging on device but I think you'll need to use a seperate api key from a signing cert to get this to work, more on signing android applications here: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: telme shortly after i get my googlemay api  how i sign in my aplication??