# Google map shows on emulator but doesn't show on device

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-maps

i m using my google map applictaion and get google map api key
  "0o8CRg5BhPmqQB1pvyYZQNfJ2ZbpDMa6XFunRwA"  i use this same key to sign in my application but problem is  map show on emulator but not show on my HTC wildfire S device tell me what is the problem??

Comment: this image show on device   www.imgur.com/p3zKC

Comment: Please check the Logcat output (in verbose or debug mode) when on the device, and look for any line like `java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3`

In that case it's a problem with the api-key you used. Try regenerating the key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android map application not showing any map on device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374870/android-map-application-not-showing-any-map-on-device)

Comment: Please donot display your key here people can misuse it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen for many cases you can try out the list of cases below which may solve this

- Try switching on WiFi Gps or data exchange for the internet access
- Check the location bases settings and switch on everything related for access location for the app.Settings>Location>SwitchOn...
- Check all the permission in    manifest.Internet,Access_fine_location, Access_coarse_location
- Check the generated key for the map.
- Check whether the network has a good speed to fetch the map.

Comment: i did my self i sign in my application create new keystore file in Location C:\deploymap\AndroidGoogleMaps.keystore give password  android and in next screen  give alias name  "androiddebugkey" password  android android get  AndroidGoogleMaps.keystore  file  and put in cmd like this 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keys
tore "C:\Documents and Settings\Nazeer\.android\AndroidGoogleMaps.keystore" -sto
repass android -keypass android

Comment: and get new finger print  and place in google site https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup and get new map api key  place this key in  xml   and   sign in application again using   exist keystore file  AndroidGoogleMaps.keystore   so now app work fine on  device

Comment: @HayyaAnam Well.. That was what I told you in my post? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the API key you're using isn't associated with the one you're signing you application with.

You will need to use another API Key which is associated with your production certificate - the one that you sign your APK with - and not the debug key.

Try to use [this guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey?hl=da#getfingerprint) instead of the one from SDK Debug Certificate

Comment: This is valid only if the OP is releasing the app. Given the OP is using the emulator could mean it's still in the debug phase, in which case using the production key is not advised.

Comment: You're right about that. Just read it like he's signing the application and using the API Key which worked with the debugkey from the emulator!

Comment: i choose new   Create new keystore  and give path of  folder  C:\myfolder\AndroidGooglemap  nad  give password previes map api key
0o8CRg5BhPmqQB1pvyYZQNfJ2ZbpDMa6XFunRwA

Answer (score 0):

A point to note is that (if debugging) you should have a separate debug-key generated for each of the machines you're using to install your app from. Only once you plan to release your app is when you can refer to @Thomas' answer and generate a release key.

In the meantime to locate any api-key related problem just check your Logcat output for `java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3`, which would mean the debug key you used is not valid for the machine you've installed the app from.

Comment: tell me just after i get my this google api key  usng this on cmd

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keys
tore "C:\Documents and Settings\Nazeer\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass andro
id -keypass android

Comment: i get this google map key  0o8CRg5BhPmqQB1pvyYZQNfJ2ZbpDMa6XFunRwA 

now what i did for sign in???

Comment: how to deploy app on real device tell by step by step what i wirte on where?

Comment: How did you deploy this for testing on your HTC device?

Answer (score 0):

use this link

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin> keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Nazeer.android\AndroidGoogleMaps.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android

Comment: i also come here again to see my last post because i also forget the method after many days so come to find my post again to see how i did this:D

Answer (score 0):

you have to add SHA-1 certificate fingerprint associated with your releaseKey.jks (used to sign apk) to your map api key:

- open terminal
- suppose your releaseKey.jks locates at:
  /Users/macbook/Downloads/Files/releaseKey.jks and your releaseKey.jks
  's alias name is demilaram, open terminal and type:

  keytool -list -v
     -keystore /Users/macbook/Downloads/Files/releaseKey.jks -alias demilaram
- copy SHA1 and navigate to Google Console and open your api key then add
  finger print and package name. under column named "SHA-1 certificate
  fingerprint" paste SHA1 and under column named as "Package name"
  enter your package name.
- hit save and after a while (probably 10 minutes) you'll be able to
  see map on your device which has a release mode apk installed on.